# How to map trapezoid image to rectangle cubemap face?

Tags: opengl, textures, uv-mapping, cubemap, 360-video

I am writing a 360 video application on oculus mobile SDK. My video frame has a trapezoid region and I need to map it into a rectangle region.

[image]

In the above figure, trapezoid `ABDC` is part of my video frame. I need to map it into a rectangle `A'B'D'C'`. The rectangle is part of a face of a cube.

At the video frame generation side, the trapezoid region is generated from a rectangle region. The bigger side of the trapezoid (AC in the abovefigure) is same as the height of rectangle (side A'C') and smaller side of trapezoid (side BD) is smaller than the height of the rectangle. I know I am loosing some details in this process and I am fine with it.

At rendering side for mapping, I need to provide the region as combination of triangles. So I gave two triangles, `ABC` and `CBD`. But sice the triangle sizes are not equal, mapping was not proper. The triangle region `CBD` expands more compare to triangle region `ABC`.

I also tried drawing diagonals to trapezoid ABDC and mapped using four triangles. Even with that logic I observed same issue.

**Update 1**
Please refer to image3(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRy9W.jpg) and image1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwOuI.jpg) of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141039/transform-rectangle-to-trapezoid-for-perspective). Please note, in my application decoded image will be like image3 and I need to render it such that it appears like image1.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to map trapezoid to rectangle?

Comment: @JohnHamilton Originally the trapezoid image is created from rectangle image. Hence it has some sort of deformation due to compression. My expectation is that when I convert the trapezoid to rectangle, there should be some stretching and the deformation should completely get eliminated.

Comment: @JohnHamilton: Trapezoid's bigger side (line AC) is same as rectangle's size and smaller side (line BD) is smaller than the rectangle's side. I know some information is lost but that is fine for me (i.e. I am ok to loose some details). But I just want to make sure that the expansion of any particular pixel column is constant for the entire column.

Comment: @JohnHamilton: Are you asking me to shrink AC at frame generation side? That is not possible. I want some sort of gradual degradation of quality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57237/discussion-between-mayurk-and-john-hamilton).